# Backtracking Problem Issues With The Backtrack Part

Tags: c, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive algorithm that when given an integer n finds the shortest path to 0 where 2 steps can be made:

1. find a and b such that a*b=n, then take max(a,b)
2. reduce by 1

What I have managed to do so far is:

```
int maxDiv(int n,int i);
int toZero(int num);
int toZeroHelper(int num);


int main(){
    toZero(150);

}

int maxDiv(int n,int i){
    if(n==1)
        return 1;
    if(n%i==0)
        return n/i;
    else{
        return maxDiv(n,i+1);
    }
}

int toZero(int num){
    if (num==1)
        return 1;
    else
        return toZeroHelper(num);
}

int toZeroHelper(int num){
    if(num==1)
        return num;
    else{
        printf("%d\n",toZeroHelper(maxDiv(num,2)));
        printf("%d\n",toZeroHelper(num-1));
        return num;
    }
}
```

What I can get is:

a. How to use backtracking, I need to check if the next step 1 returns a smaller number than 2 or the opposite?

b. How do I get to the shortest path?

Any references/links/etc. will be useful

Comment: What you called `maxDiv()` is usually called `gcd()` (greatest common divisor) but that's a matter of taste and not an issue. So far, the function seems to be OK but I believe it's the wrong approach. I read _1. find a and b, such a*b=n_ as **any** a and b for which a * b = n. This gives for most numbers (except primes) multiple candidate pairs. Hence, you had problems to apply backtracking - it makes sense only if there are alternatives to test. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I should know better but I couldn't resist to puzzle this out. To make this pedagogically worth, I will explain extensively:

First a short recall of [Backtracking (from Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking):

> Backtracking is a general algorithm for finding all (or some) solutions to some computational problems, notably constraint satisfaction problems, that incrementally builds candidates to the solutions, and abandons a candidate ("backtracks") as soon as it determines that the candidate cannot possibly be completed to a valid solution.

There are two pre-requisites for this:

1. There is a recursive search algorithm.
2. In every recursion step, there are potentially alternatives to compare.

Backtracking means to discard the recursively found result of one alternative when the recursively found result of another alternative leads to a better result.

Disclaimer: Recursive algorithms don't need necessarily implemented with recursive functions. Alternatively, iteration with a data stack could be used as well. However, recursive functions are IMHO the most intuitive approach to implement recursive algorithms.

I'm not sure whether I understood the attempt of OP correctly but I believe OP oversaw the fact that there might be multiple candidates (*a*, *b*) for an *n* which satisfy *a · b = n*. These multiple candidates may provide varying solutions, and, hence, this is a point where backtracking can be applied to determine the best solution concerning the defined minimum criterion (i.e. the shortest path to 0).

A simple (and, may be, naïve) approach to find all candidates (*a*, *b*) is to count *a* downwards from *n* to *1*, and to compute *b* by *b = n / a*. For `int` numbers this will yield a pair (*a*, *b*) where *a · b ≤ n*. With a condition *a · b == n* this can be checked afterwards to sort this out:

```
for (int a = n; a >= 1; --a) {
  int b = n / a;
  if (a * b != n) continue;
  // sufficient pair (a, b) found
}
```

It's also required that only *max(a, b)* has to be considered. For our luck, multiplication of `int`s is commutative, i.e. if (*a*, *b*) is a solution then (*b*, *a*) is as well. Hence, it's sufficient to stop as soon as *a = b* because the following solutions (*a*, *b*) were already checked as (*b*, *a*). Hence, *a* will always satisfy *max(a, b)* as required:

```
for (int a = n; a >= 1; --a) {
  int b = n / a;
  if (a < b) break; // symmetric solutions which are already tested
  if (a * b != n) continue;
  // sufficient pair (a, b) found
}
```

For each `sufficient pair (a, b)`, step 2 has to be applied (one down) and the recursion has to be entered:

```
find(int n)
{
  for (int a = n; a >= 1; --a) {
    int b = n / a;
    if (a < b) break; // symmetric solutions which are already tested
    if (a * b != n) continue;
    // sufficient pair (a, b) found
    find(a - 1);
  }
}
```

The recursion is still not terminated. Hence, a test for `n == 0` should be added:

```
find(int n)
{
  if (n == 0) return; // start backtracking
  for (int a = n; a >= 1; --a) {
    int b = n / a;
    if (a < b) break; // symmetric solutions which are already tested
    if (a * b != n) continue;
    // sufficient pair (a, b) found
    find(a - 1);
  }
}
```

The backtracking is still missing. To apply backtracking, a prerequisite is that the solutions are quantified concerning a criterion. For shortest path, a sufficient approach should be to count the number of recursive calls (the recursion depth). To achieve this, the (still not yet defined) return value of function can be used:

```
int find(int n)
```

For termination condition `(n == 0)`, 0 is returned (assuming, the length of path to reach 0 from 0 is 0 by definition). Otherwise it is 1 more than the found shortest path. To determine the shortest path, all path lengths found in one loop are compared, and the minimum wins.

```
int find(int n)
{
  if (n == 0) return 0; // start backtracking with path length 0
  int lenMin;
  for (int a = n; a >= 1; --a) {
    int b = n / a;
    if (a < b) break; // symmetric solutions which are already tested
    if (a * b != n) continue;
    // sufficient pair (a, b) found
    int len = find(a - 1);
    // override lenMin if a shorter path was found
    if (lenMin > len) lenMin = len;
  }
  return lenMin + 1;
}
```

The initialization of `lenMin` is still missing. A simple approach would be to introduce an additional flag (e.g. `int lenMinSet`) to ensure that `lenMin` is assigned for first found result and compared for the following only. However, this can be done better: `lenMin` has to be initialized with a sufficiently large value which is definitely beaten by the result of first call (which even could be the final result). My first thought was `INT_MAX`. Thinking twice, I realized that the longest path cannot be longer than `n`. I came to this idea by assuming there would be a path for which every *a = n* (and *b = 1*). So, the path would be (*n*, *n-1*, *n-2*, ..., *1*). Every node in a path where *a < n* makes the result even shorter. (If I were clever enough in Mathematics I probably would be able to prove this by [induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) but as it is you have to believe me.)

So, this is the final function to determine the shortest path to 0:

```
int find(int n)
{
  if (n == 0) return 0; // start backtracking with path length 0
  int lenMin = n;
  for (int a = n; a >= 1; --a) {
    int b = n / a;
    if (a < b) break; // symmetric solutions which are already tested
    if (a * b != n) continue;
    // sufficient pair (a, b) found
    int len = find(a - 1);
    // override lenMin if a shorter path was found
    if (lenMin > len) lenMin = len;
  }
  return lenMin + 1;
}
```

<kbd>[**Live demo on ideone**](https://ideone.com/fratgm)</kbd>

That looks quite nice but it would be even more convincing when the path itself would be exposed. The problem is: The path can hardly be printed in the recursive function `find()` – it might be discarded later by back-tracking. So, the path needs to be recorded somehow and printed finally when the overall shortest path has been definitely found.

To achieve this, an additional parameter has to be added to `find()` to provide storage for the path. For the necessary size of the storage, the already determined upper boundary for length is good as well. The pity is that the size of storage (resp. its upper boundary) depends on n. [Variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) would be a nice solution. Unfortunately, although VLAs are standardized since C99, they are optionally by standard. (I recently read in SO that even VS2017 still seems not to support them.) So, for a portable solution, this has to be fiddled with `malloc()` and `free()`:

```
void printShortestPath(int n)
{
  if (n <= 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "n should be > 0!\n");
    return;
  }
  int *path = malloc(n * sizeof n);
  int len = find(n, path);
  printf("Length of shortest path to %d: %d\n", n, len);
  printf("Path:");
  for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) printf(" %d", path[i]);
  putchar('\n');
  free(path);
}
```

Btw., `malloc()` and `free()` are more stack-friendly than VLAs (because allocating on heap), and I realized that a lot of people in this community are very critical concerning extensive stack usage.

`find()` has to be modified accordingly:

```
int find(int n, int *path)
```

This arises another issue: When `find()` is called recursively it fills the path which may or may not be discarded afterwards. So, it should store the provided path in a local copy until it's sure that it is part of the final solution.

```
int find(int n, int *pathMin)
{
  if (n == 0) return 0; // start backtracking with path length 0
  pathMin[0] = n;
  if (n == 1) return 1; // trivial result
  int lenMin = n;
  int *path = malloc(n * sizeof n);
  for (int a = n; a > 1; --a) {
    int b = n / a;
    if (a < b) break; // symmetric solutions which are already tested
    if (a * b != n) continue;
    // sufficient pair (a, b) found
    int len = find(a - 1, path);
    // override lenMin if a shorter path was found
    if (lenMin > len) {
      lenMin = len;
      // store current shortest path (it could be final result)
      memcpy(pathMin + 1, path, len * sizeof *path);
    }
  }
  free(path);
  return lenMin + 1;
}
```

Putting this all together (with a small brute-force test):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int find(int n, int *pathMin)
{
  if (n == 0) return 0; // start backtracking with path length 0
  pathMin[0] = n;
  if (n == 1) return 1; // trivial result
  int lenMin = n;
  int *path = malloc(n * sizeof n);
  for (int a = n; a > 1; --a) {
    int b = n / a;
    if (a < b) break; // symmetric solutions which are already tested
    if (a * b != n) continue;
    // sufficient pair (a, b) found
    int len = find(a - 1, path);
    // override lenMin if a shorter path was found
    if (lenMin > len) {
      lenMin = len;
      // store current shortest path (it could be final result)
      memcpy(pathMin + 1, path, len * sizeof *path);
    }
  }
  free(path);
  return lenMin + 1;
}

void printShortestPath(int n)
{
  if (n <= 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "n should be > 0!\n");
    return;
  }
  int *path = malloc(n * sizeof n);
  int len = find(n, path);
  printf("Length of shortest path to %d: %d\n", n, len);
  printf("Path:");
  for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) printf(" %d", path[i]);
  putchar('\n');
  free(path);
}

int main(void)
{
  // a brute-force test for a range of numbers:
  for (int n = 1; n <= 20; ++n) {
    printShortestPath(n);
  }
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Length of shortest path to 1: 1
Path: 1
Length of shortest path to 2: 2
Path: 2 1
Length of shortest path to 3: 3
Path: 3 2 1
Length of shortest path to 4: 2
Path: 4 1
Length of shortest path to 5: 3
Path: 5 4 1
Length of shortest path to 6: 3
Path: 6 2 1
Length of shortest path to 7: 4
Path: 7 6 2 1
Length of shortest path to 8: 4
Path: 8 3 2 1
Length of shortest path to 9: 3
Path: 9 2 1
Length of shortest path to 10: 3
Path: 10 4 1
Length of shortest path to 11: 4
Path: 11 10 4 1
Length of shortest path to 12: 4
Path: 12 5 4 1
Length of shortest path to 13: 5
Path: 13 12 5 4 1
Length of shortest path to 14: 4
Path: 14 6 2 1
Length of shortest path to 15: 3
Path: 15 4 1
Length of shortest path to 16: 4
Path: 16 15 4 1
Length of shortest path to 17: 5
Path: 17 16 15 4 1
Length of shortest path to 18: 4
Path: 18 5 4 1
Length of shortest path to 19: 5
Path: 19 18 5 4 1
Length of shortest path to 20: 3
Path: 20 4 1
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on ideone**](https://ideone.com/VAej4C)</kbd>

Comment: Perhaps I am mistaken, but I believe the problem is to *choose* between gcd and decrementing on each step. So, for 18 I would expect `18 6 3 2 1`, for example (I still upvoted since this doesn't change the overall algorithm too much).

Comment: @Groo Yeah. From the requirements of 1. and 2. step, I didn't see any restriction to gcd but I might have mis-understood. You may write an alternative answer. ;-)

Comment: I believe OP should have a good base to tweak this, no need to me to repeat it. I think this is a homework assignment because I saw a similar question a couple of days ago and it seemed like the problem was to choose one of two steps. I also don't understand the mind of a person who would downvote this.

Comment: @Groo I agree. May be, it's even better for OP when I implemented the wrong algorithm. So, OP can fix her/his own approach and is on the safe side. (I assume that teachers/professors are able to use the Internet as well, although students might not be aware of this fact.) ;-)